# Javascript: Double sided conversion on input values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have two `<input type="numer">` tags to convert a currency between eachother.

### HTML

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="number" id="credits" onkeydown="creditsToCash()" onkeypress="creditsToCash()" value="" placeholder="Credits"/>
    <input type="number" id="cash" onkeydown="cashToCredits()" onkeypress="cashToCredits()" value="" placeholder="Cash"/>
</form>
```

### *JavaScript*

```
var credits = document.getElementById('credits'),
cash = document.getElementById('cash');
function creditsToCash(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        crd = credits.value;
        crd2ch = crd / 2.5;
        cash.setAttribute('value', crd2ch);
    }, 10);
}
function cashToCredits(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        ch = cash.value;
        ch2crd = ch * 2.5;
        credits.setAttribute('value', ch2crd);
    }, 10);
}
```

It works if I type a number on one side only, but if I try to change the result on the other `<input>` the whole script fails completely till I refresh the page.

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console when " the whole script fails completely"?

Comment: It gives no error. The script stops working on both input tags if I try to change the converted value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear timeouts when they are unused

```
var credits = document.getElementById('credits'),
cash = document.getElementById('cash');
var cashId = null;
var creditsId = null;
function creditsToCash(){
    if (cashId != null) clearTimeout(cashId);
    creditsId = setTimeout(function() {
        crd = credits.value;
        crd2ch = crd / 2.5;
        cash.setAttribute('value', crd2ch);
    }, 10);
}
function cashToCredits(){
    if (creditsId != null) clearTimeout(creditsId);
    cashId = setTimeout(function() {
        ch = cash.value;
        ch2crd = ch * 2.5;
        credits.setAttribute('value', ch2crd);
    }, 10);
}
```

Comment: Same issue. If I changed the converted value on the opposite input the script stops working.